# Use of NULL local variable for List<dynamic> in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, webmatrix

The best solution I could find (anywhere) to get results from an SQL Query into a local variable was to use a NULL `List<dynamic>` or `IEnumerable<dynamic>` variable declaration.

Creating the variable by doing something like:

```
@{
    IEnumerable<dynamic> myVariable = null;
}
```

The variable can then get a value from a database query like:

```
@{
    try
    {
        Database db = Database.Open("name"); // name of connectionString configured in web.config
        string myQuery = "EXEC dbo.Get_Results @Param1=@0, @Param2=@1";
        myVariable = db.Query(myQuery, @Param1, @Param2);
        db.Close();
        db.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Do something
    }
```

Which allows me to do something like the following:

```
@if(myVariable != null)
{
    foreach (var row in myVariable)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

This is working perfectly, but what I am still curious is how to do the same using `List<dynamic>`, as an alternative to using `IEnumerable<dynamic>` the way I am using it.

**What is the `List<dynamic>` equivalent solution that I am using for `IEnumerable<dynamic>`?**

I know my question itself is very simple, but it took me a long time to get past trying to solve *can't implicitly convert* errors when I tried to create a Class that could receive the results from `db.Query(commandText)` into a pre-declared variable. So I thought I should provide more detail in case this helps someone else trying to figure out the same or similar. I found my solution on the `IEnumerable<dynamic>` in unrelated topic which opened my eyes to much simpler solution to problem I was trying to solve.

Comment: Don't use String.Format() to build sql strings like that. It's **very bad**.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: He's actually using that needlessly.

Comment: The `List<dynamic>` solution I had been trying earlier had me using that. The way I am doing with `IEnumerable<dynamic>` does not require use of String.Format. I am fixing in my code example here. Thanks.

Comment: I got the solution working with `List<dynamic>` by switching out three lines with the ones shown here. **A** `List<dynamic> ClientInvoice = null;` **B** `string myQuery = String.Format("EXEC dbo.Get_Results @Param1={0}, @Param2='{1}'", @Param1, @Param2);` **C** `myVariable = db.Query(myQuery).ToList();`. Back to using `String.Format` because I can't use `ToList()` on `db.Query(myQuery,@Param1,@Param2)` which gives error **'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection' does not contain a definition for 'ToList'**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Enumerable.Empty<string>()` is not null.  It is an empty sequence of strings.  Note, for example, that the following code prints "false":

```
var sequence = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
Console.WriteLine(sequence == null);
```

You probably want to create a new (empty) list:

```
List<dynamic> x = new List<dynamic>();
```

or, if you really need the list variable to hold a null reference:

```
List<dynamic> x = null;
```

Comment: Both `List<dynamic> x = new List<dynamic();` and `List<dynamic> x = null;` are working. Also, 100% correct on `Enumerable.Empty<string>()` not being `null`. I am sure `null` was one of the first values I had tried, but something else in the code needed fixing. Thanks

Comment: PS - I am able to declare `IEnumerable<dynamic> x = null;` which works.